# Error while install Android application on Android device? (Blocked application.)

Tags: android

I am making an application in Android. This is a small application of an image gallery. Then I want to run it on my Android device, after pressing the install button it will give me an error like this:

[For security, your phone is set to block installation of applications not sourced in android Market.]

Can you give me a solution so that I can install the application on my Android phone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your phone open the settings app and click applications. Then check the box to allow unknown sources. Also click deelopement and click the box to allow usb debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings application in your device, 
Applications -> Unknown Sources -> Allow install of non-Market Applications (Enabled)

Then try installing your app.

Answer (score 1):

Open: **Settings** -> **Applications** and check the **Unknown sources**'s checkbox.

Comment: Thanks now my application is installed

Comment: in my device its in Settings -> Security and checked Unknown sources